# Laravel 5.4 AdminLTE CKEditor - editor not showing options

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-5.4, adminlte

Environment:

1. XAMPP
2. Windows 10 home

Using:

1. Laravel 5.4
2. AdminLTE

Objective:
I'm trying to add **CKEditor** to my AdminLTE dashboard Page, but when I follow [these steps](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/blob/master/pages/forms/editors.html) it comes up in my page with no toolbar like this [image]

Code:

```
     <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">CK Editor
            <small>Advanced and full of features</small>
          </h3>
          <!-- tools box -->
          <div class="pull-right box-tools">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Remove">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
          <!-- /. tools -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body pad">
          <form>
                <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                                        This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
                </textarea>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and the JS code:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1')
            //bootstrap WYSIHTML5 - text editor
            //$('.textarea').wysihtml5()
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: check the console if there is any problem, and make sur your are calling ckeditor.js

Comment: you can check the official documentation to see how to use it. https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html

Comment: when I read the docs of adminlte it says it comes with ck editor, but I don't understand how to use it in laravel , I've searched a lot for the three gathered (Laravel / adminlte / ckeditor )but it comes to nothing.

Comment: Have you added `css` and `js` for it?? Also if added, then check it in browser using view page source and confirm it with perfect path includes or not! If it's all done then make console in `$(function () {` and check if it called or not?? Verify this path example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('js/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: @PoulaAdel: Is it helps you??

Comment: @HirenGohel yes, could you make it clear for others in an answer ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel: Yeah, sure  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in includes of `css` and `js` path. Also if you are added it both, then check it in browser using view page source and confirm it with perfect path includes or not!

If it's all done then make console in `$(function () {` and check if it called or not?

If you don't know how to add path for css and js in laravel, please refer below thing:

**CSS** path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css') }}">
```

**JS** path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('js/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js') }}"></script>
```

After including path, you need to add `HTML` and `JS` code for **CkEditor** as you used in your question!!

Hope this will fixed your issue!!